# woocommerce doesn't fire webhooks between two natted servers

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

Using a cloud solution my servers are behind a firewall and NATted with private class IPs.

- my shop site: shop.example.com (192.168.1.10)
- my web site: www.example.com (192.168.1.20)

I create a webhook that call an URL of web site every time an item is added to the cart:
[image: webhook configuration]

But webhook is never fired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having read all the documentation I found (few pages) I found the **wordpress** allows to place an http request only for self and public IPs, using `wp_http_validate_url`, his behavior can be override by a filter: `http_request_host_is_external`

In *functions.php* I add the override hook:

```
add_filter( 'http_request_host_is_external','allowed_http_request_hosts_local', 10, 2 );
```

and the implementation of the function with the address of my web server:

```
function allowed_http_request_hosts_local( $is_external, $host ) {
    $hosts_white_list=[];
    $hosts_white_list[]="www.example.com";
    if ( ! $is_external && in_array($host,$hosts_white_list) )
        $is_external = true;
       return $is_external;
}
```

Wordpress schedules the webhooks in the cron-table so they are firing when WP call himself at *shop.example.com/wp_cron.php*
Many firewall don't allow to call the public IP behind the firewall, so I ended the configuration adding the private address of the shop to his */etc/hosts*:

```
192.168.1.10 shop.example.com
```

And all work well!